# Play Json - update a field (hash it)

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I have the following validator for json login:

```
  val loginValidator: Reads[JsObject] = (
    ((__ \ 'username).json.pickBranch(Reads.of[JsString]) or
      (__ \ 'email).json.pickBranch(Reads.of[JsString] keepAnd email)) and
    (__ \ 'pw).json.pickBranch(Reads.of[JsString])
  ).reduce
```

How can I get this to also hash the password using a function: String => String (let's say it's a method Password.hash(plain: String)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this appears to work:

```
  val loginValidator: Reads[JsObject] = (
    ((__ \ 'username).json.pickBranch(Reads.of[JsString]) or
      (__ \ 'email).json.pickBranch(Reads.of[JsString] keepAnd email)) and
    (__ \ 'pw).json.pickBranch(Reads.of[JsString]).map(a => Json.obj("pw" -> User.Password.hash((a \ "pw").as[String])))
  ).reduce
```

But it seems like there is still a better way than this. Does anybody know?